# how can I convert columns into row in mysql work bench

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :

[image]

But I what to be look like this. How can I change it using mysql workbench syntax ?

[image]

Comment: please edit your question and paster your table data here else images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select max(case when id = 1 then col1 end) as `10`,
           max(case when id = 2 then col1 end) as `20`,
           max(case when id = 3 then col1 end) as `30`      
    from ((select id, `one`as col1, 1 as col2 from t1) union all
          (select id, two, 2 as col2 from t1) union all
          (select id, three, 3 as col2 from t1) union all
          (select id, four, 4 as col2 from t1) union all
          (select id, five, 5 as col2 from t1)
         ) temp
    group by col2;
```